# Performance/Memory optimization with hashmap and weakhasmap

Tags: java, hashmap, weakhashmap

I have a question related to hashmap and weakhashmap.In my application, I will fetch 100k records from DB every time and put it in a map. After I do some manipulations with first set of records, I will fetch next 100k records.

In this situation, which map implementation is appropriate? Is there any better data structure to hold such huge data?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: ...probably a `HashMap`.  Size of data doesn't matter nearly as much as what you need to do with that data.